# Specifying non-numeric value for an Option Set option in Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I know that by default CRM option set accepts an integer value for its options' values. I was just trying to figure out if there is any workaround for specifying a non-numeric value like OPT1 instead of a numeric value like 1 for an option.

The reason I need this functionality is because my CRM application interacts with another application that uses codes like IN,US,UK,AU,etc for countries. Hence I need a corresponding mapping in CRM for those codes.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No its not possible to store non int value. I think you can handle the mappings in code in other applications. For Example you can use Enums as below:

```cs
enum FieldName
{
    India = 100000000,
    USA = 100000001,
    UnitedKingdom = 100000002
};

switch(externalCode)
{
case "IN":
    {
        return (int)FieldName.India;        
    }
case "UK":
    {
        return (int)FieldName.UnitedKingdom;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking something on the same lines of maintaining this information in db.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a mapping entity for each option set you have to map.

For example, if your option set was countries:

```
  Label           Value
{ India,          100000001 }
{ USA,            100000002 }
{ United Kingdom, 100000003 }
```

Create a Countries Entity that contains your country option set as a field, and a field for your mapping text.

```
  Country   Mapping
{ 10000001, IN }
{ 10000002, US }
{ 10000003, UK }
```

Comment: didn't notice that also you suggest the creation of an entity, BlueSam screenshot is more effective :) +1

Comment: @GuidoPreite What?  You don't like my Ascii tables?  ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could create an entity that has a code (your non-numeric value) attribute and an attribute with the option set type you used in your other entity. You would then create a record for each of the values in your option set.

If you go with this approach, make sure you are using a global option set so you don't have to manage two different sets.

[image: Creating an attribute that references a global option set]

Comment: this is a good alternative solution, but during the implementation it is necessary to take care of duplicate entries for the same optionset value and role privileges for the users to access to this new entity

Comment: btw, don't consider my previous comment as assumptive, I wrote it as reminder to myself in case I need to implement this scenario :)